# Compress multiple files individually with 7zip

Tags: shell, compression, 7zip

Searching I noticed that it was possible to compress several files individually by gzip. Unfortunately this format is not useful to me.

I tried to compose with the following command.

```
Find. -type f -name "* .txt" -exec 7z {} \;
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a file to archive, you should use "a" command: `7z a archive.7z file`. So your command should be like this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec 7z a $(basename {}).7z {} \;
```

or, if you want archive names like ".txt.7z",

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec 7z a {}.7z {} \;
```

`basename` here is to get your file name without extension.

Comment: I love Linux!! Thanks!!